# Vue router open a new tab with params (Params are empty)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am openining a new tab by using vue-router and passing some params. I don't want to pass query params because i don't want user to see them. so whenever a new page is opened the params that i pass don't exist. I think it should be possible to access to those params even if i open in a new page, right?

```
      let routeData = this.$router.resolve({ path: '/link/component', params: {
      param1: 'value1',
      param2: 'value2',
  }})
  
      window.open(routeData.href, '_blank')
```

and in my component i try to access the params this way but it's undefined.

```
console.log("this",this.$route.params)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to pass hidden (not shown in URL) parameters to the new window:

Before opening the page, save the parameters:

```js
localStorage['params'] = JSON.stringify({
  param1: 'value1',
  param2: 'value2',
})
```

Then restore them in your component when needed:

```js
let params = {}
try {
  params = JSON.parse(localStorage['params'])
} catch (error) {
  // ignore
}
```

Comment: hmm that's a good idea. So that means i can't pass it via router when i open a new page like tried doing it in my original code?

Comment: Right, data can't be locally passed to new tabs/windows without using some kind of Storage API; and Vue Router does not use Storage for this, so you'd have to roll your own solution as shown above.

Comment: gotcha! I mark your answer as accepted since there's no other way to do it then!